# bulk insertion in MS SQL from a text file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, insert, database

I have a text file that contains around 21 lac entries and I want to insert all these entries into a table. Initially I have created one function in c# that read line by line and insert into table but it takes too much time. Please suggest an efficient way to insert these bulk data and that file is containing TAB(4 spaces) as delimiter.
And that text file also containing some duplicate entries and I don't want to insert those entries.

Comment: Try removing constraints from your table and drop indexes. You might also want to look into BULK INSERT sql statement.

Comment: That text file have some duplicate entries and I don't want to insert those entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load all of your data into a `DataTable` object and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to bulk insert them:

```
DataTable dtData = new DataTable("Data");

// load your data here

using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection("db conn string"))
{
    dbConn.Open();

    using (SqlTransaction dbTrans = dbConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy dbBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, dbTrans))
            {
                dbBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "intended SQL table name";
                dbBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtData );
            }

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            dbTrans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }

    dbConn.Close();
}
```

I've included the example to wrap this into a `SqlTransaction` so there will be a full rollback if there's a failure along the way.  To get you started, [here's a good CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6737/Fill-a-DataSet-from-delimited-text-files) on loading the delimited data into a `DataSet` object.

**Sanitizing the data before loading**

OK, here's how I think your data looks:

```
CC_FIPS    FULL_NAME_ND 
AN         Xixerella
AN         Vila 
AN         Sornas
AN         Soldeu
AN         Sispony
... (cut down for brevity)
```

In this instance you want to create your `DataTable` like this:

```
DataTable dtData = new DataTable("Data");
dtData.Columns.Add("CC_FIPS");
dtData.Columns.Add("FULL_NAME_ND");
```

Then you want to iterate each row (assuming your tab delimited data is separated row-by-row by carriage returns) and check whether this data already exists in the `DataTable` using the `.Select` method and if there is a match (i'm checking for BOTH values, it's up to you whether you want to do something else) then don't add it thereby preventing duplicates.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("path to your file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string line = string.Empty;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            // use a row index to skip the header row as you don't want to insert CC_FIPS and FULL_NAME_ND
            if (rowIndex > 0)
            {
                // split your data up into a 2-d array tab delimited
                string[] parts = line.Split('\t');

                // now check whether this data has already been added to the datatable
                DataRow[] rows = dtData.Select("CC_FIPS = '" + parts[0] + "' and FULL_NAME_ND = '" + parts[1] + "'");
                if (rows.Length == 0)
                {
                    // if there're no rows, then the data doesn't exist so add it
                    DataRow nr = dtData.NewRow();
                    nr["CC_FIPS"] = parts[0];
                    nr["FULL_NAME_ND"] = parts[1];
                    dtData.Rows.Add(nr);
                }
            }

            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of this you should have a sanitized `DataTable` that you can bulk insert. Please note that this code isn't tested, but it's a best guess as to how you should do it. There are many ways this can be done, and probably a lot better than this method (specifically LINQ) - but it's a starting point.

Comment: That text file have some duplicate entries and I don't want to insert those entries. So how can I neglect these entries ?

Comment: @PuneetPurohit you need to sanitize your data (preferably) before loading into the `DataTable`. There are many ways you could do this. Personally I would create a derived, sanitized set from your existing data and load the derived set into the `DataTable`. Can we see a sample of your data?

Comment: CC_FIPS FULL_NAME_ND
AN Xixerella
AN Vila
AN Sornas
AN Soldeu
AN Sispony
AN Segudet
AN El Tarter
AN Sant Julia de Loria
AN Sant Joan de Caselles
AN Santa Coloma
AN Ransol
AN Prats
AN Pas de la Casa
AN Pal
AN Ordino
AN Nagol
AN Molleres
AN Meritxell
AN Mas de Ribafeta
AN Mas d'Alins
AN Llumeneres
AN Llorts

Comment: These are the sample data..Sorry I am not allowed to show actual data and this data contains country-code and city-name